# Encoding issue python

Tags: python, encoding, lxml

My question is about the en- and decoding of strings in Python.

If I define

```
s = "être"
```

using `print s`, I get the correct representation of `s`.

How can I, using `lxml` and the set-function, write the correct representation (`être`) to an `xml` file?

Just typing `w.set("attr", s)` does not work:

```
"ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters"
```

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Which encoding are you using for your source file? I'm assuming you're on Python 2, right?

Comment: You're assuming right. And, I try to use utf-8. But the source-file could also have latin1 (possible?) as encoding... [it comes from another program...]

Comment: Thanks for the information (looking closer at your question, it's obvious you're using Python 2). My first attempt at an answer was probably missing the point, the current version should be more useful :)

Comment: Hm printing the source-word out, I get: �tre What encoding is this? :S

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you transform your string to Unicode, either by using

```
s = u"être"
```

or by decoding the string (for example, if your script is in `latin-1`):

```
s = "être"
s = s.decode("latin-1")
```

before passing it to `lxml`.

Comment: Hm printing the source-word out, I get: �tre What encoding is this? :S

Comment: @MarkF6: It's a Unicode object which doesn't *have*  an encoding. Before printing it, you need to convert it back to the encoding your terminal is using (but you said you didn't want to print it but pass it to `lxml` which is expecting Unicode objects).